# CRM - Query records with 'incompatible' combinations of values (SQL, SSRS)

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have a record type in my CRM environment where there are two lookups. There are certain combinations of values that aren't "valid," but no constraint in the system to prevent that entry. To illustrate, I'll use a small sample of cities and states to explain.

External to the CRM, I have a spreadsheet to show what combinations of cities and states are okay and which aren't; for example, Boston is a city in MA, but not in MN, TX, or WI. Arlington, however, is a city in all four states, etc.:

[image]

The problem is there's nothing stopping someone from putting "Cambridge" for the city and "TX" for the state, for example. My hope was to somehow use this spreadsheet's data as an input combined with a SQL query to create an SSRS report that would show records with incompatible combinations:

```
SELECT name, city, state
FROM contacts
WHERE [magic for the query to know there's no Cambridge in Texas, etc.]
```

I could go through and define each of the combinations as valid or not in the query itself, but something tells me there's a more efficient way to do this instead of defining the several hundred possible combinations that I have.

I'm working on configuring the fields so valid entry is forced, but I need to identify and clean up the existing entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a table of valid combinations. If you don't already have one, then you'll need to create one. The simplest form would be something like

```
CREATE TABLE CityState(City varchar(50), State varchar(2))

INSERT INTO CityState VALUES
('Boston', 'MA'),
('Arlington', 'MN'),
('Arlington', 'MA'),
('Arlington', 'TX'),
('Arlington', 'WI')
```

etc...

Once you have this, your query would be something like

```
SELECT c.name, c.city, c.state,
       CASE s.City WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsValid
    FROM contacts c
        LEFT JOIN CityState s ON c.city = s.City AND c.state = s.State
```

Comment: Ah, okay - I understand. I can use Excel to pretty easily convert my existing table into the values you're describing there, so creating the table shouldn't be too bad.

Do I then drop that reference table at the end of the query? I haven't ever done queries that involve anything other than SELECT statements, so I'm not totally sure how that works.

Comment: Never mind - I suppose there's no reason not to just leave the table there and update it as needed, right? Then keep the SELECT statement as a separate script altogether. Thanks again - I'll consider this answered!

Comment: That's right. I would create the table and keep it. Reference tables like that make up a large part of my databases where validation rules are required.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a reference table with the field names, City and State. Populate accordingly where by they cross ref as "Y". You would end up with a table with 19 rows of data.

Use this table in your main dataset linking on city names and amend your query, ie: 
SELECT name, city, state
FROM contacts inner join reference_table on contacts.city = reference_table.city